# Is there a way to put a call function to show the top holders address of an ERC20 token in Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20

Looking to find a way to show top holder/holders of an ERC20 token I've created. I'm using Remix.

Answer (score 0):

ERC20 standard doesn't have any such function implemented as a standard, but you can add it to the code.

Since ERC20 stored balances in *_balances* mapping, there is no simple way to get a list of all holders, so you will need to create your own array *owners*
and add or remove new owners every time transaction or mint happens. Then you can simply iterate through the array with a for loop and return the ordered list.

So no there is no simple way to do this on-chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an array to push all token holders and then outside blockchain you an write a function like:

The implementation in the contract:

```
address[] holders;
uint 256 holder;
```

An logic on ethers:

```
const getTopHolders= async () => {
    try {
        let topHolders = []
        let holdersWithBalance = []
        const holders = await contract.holder();
        for(let i = 0; i < holders; i++){
            const result = await factory.holders(i)
            topHolders.push(result)
        }
        topHolders.map( async (data) => {
        const balanceOf = await contract.balanceOf(data)
        holdersWithBalance.push({address: data, balance: 
        Number(balanceOf._hex))}
       }
       return holdersWithBalance
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

And then you order by the balance.